# android c2dm navigate the jumpNote source code

Tags: android, android-c2dm

all,when i open jumpNote project in eclipse,i encounter some mistakes like the following description.

many variables related with c2dm like
Config.C2DM_ACCOUNT_EXTRA,
Config.C2DM_MESSAGE_SYNC,
Config.C2DM_SENDER etc
****cannot be resolved.****
i uses the latest sdk(2.2).
any one konws the reasons, i think that if i miss some jar files?
any help is grateful.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check out trunk/src.shared and merge it into the src dir of jumpnote.  Then clean/build.  If it still doesn't work re-import it into eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Those are just examples of what you can do in your own app, they don't actually exist within the Android API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Config class if you browse the source code, com.example.jumpnote.android.Config.java